# How to resolve the conflict between jquery and mootools 1.11?

Tags: javascript, html, mootools

the slide show in my page stops working when I add the mootools script. How to resolve that?

```
    <!--Script-->
<script type='text/javascript' src="js/jquery.1.3.2.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery.cycle.all.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/presentationCycle.js'></script>

<!--mootools for dropdown-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/mootools.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/elSelect.js"></script>



<script type="text/javascript">
<!---//
window.addEvent('domready', function(){
var mySelect = new elSelect( {container : 'mySelect'} );

var mySelect2 = new elSelect( {container : 'mySelect2'} );

var mySelect3 = new elSelect( {container : 'mySelect3'} );

var mySelect4 = new elSelect( {container : 'mySelect4'} );
});
//-->
</script>
```

Comment: To prevent conflicts with jquery, use `jQuery.noConflict();`. Not sure if this is the problem, but it might help.

Comment: Uh, MooTools is Javascript. It would only cause problems if you were using the library. Are you inadvertently calling MooTools code where you shouldn't be? What's in elSelect?

Comment: since when "javascript" has become another name for "jquery" ?

Comment: haha @teresko - the nail on the head. +1

Answer (score 1):

presentationCycle.js is badly written - it uses $ instead of jQuery (and $ is used also by mootools)

You have to enclose presentationCycle in:

```
(function($) {
    ...
})(jQuery);
```

apart from that, read:

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

Comment: Since MooTools 1.2.4, there's no need for using any compatibility modes.

Comment: http://www.cult-f.net/elselect/ = eselect is OLD. way pre-mootools 1.2.4. get a more recent one that will be fine...